# Java Socket class is lying regarding connection status

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

We have a Java client that keeps a persistent socket connection open to a remote server.  The client polls a DB table every 15 seconds and if there a new item, it serializes and writes it to the socket.

Before writing to the output stream, I would like to check whether socket connection is still good.  For the specific application logic doing this proactive check is simpler than catching an exception and reconnecting reactively.

I used following code figure out which method can let me know when the connection is broken:

```
LOG.debug("Socket status: bound=" + _socket.isBound() + ", closed=" + _socket.isClosed() + ", connected=" + _socket.isConnected() + ", outputShutdown=" + _socket.isOutputShutdown() + ", inputShutdown=" + _socket.isOutputShutdown());
```

I briefly disable my network adapter and during the next polling, as expected, there was an exception while writing to the socket.

However, the debug statement printed the following:

```
"Socket status: bound=true, closed=false, connected=true, outputShutdown=false, inputShutdown=false"
```

I expected either closed to be true or connected to be false.  What actual values I get seem to be a lie.

Is there a way to reliably check the connection status of a socket?

Comment: Not sure if it relates to the issue but in the sample code you're checking `isOutputShutdown()` twice and not checking `isInputShutdown()` at all

Comment: They are not a lie, you are just misinterpreting them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java Network Programming by Elliot Rusty Harold offers the following gem:

"...To tell if a socket is currently open, you need to check that isConnected() returns true and isClosed() returns false. For example:

```
boolean connected = socket.isConnected() && ! socket.isClosed();"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is a good answer, but bear in mind that the peer may become disconnected without sending a proper TCP closure. This is neither common nor exceedingly rare. Thus `connected` may be true but the next  socket operation will fail. Thus you must still have some mechanism to deal with failure, so the above line will probably not save you any coding.

Comment: @GregS: you are quite right. I wonder why the authors of Socket's API chose not to provide a convenience method to help sort out whether a Socket is connected at all. Back to your answer in the meantime!

Comment: It is because TCP has no way of supplying the answer. If the underlying transport can't provide the info then no API built on top of it can.

Comment: Elliotte Rusty Harolde is completely wrong about this, and he is not in general reliable about aspects of this sort. `isConnected()` tells you whether you have ever connected the Socket. `isClosed()` tells you whether you have everclosed it. Neither of them changes in response to changes in the state of the *connection*. They are both about the *socket,* not the *connection.*

Comment: @EJP You are right, it is wrong and perhaps, the correct answer is, there is no way to tell due to limitations in TCP itself, apart from failed read or write attempts.

Comment: @Arvanem Exactly, so fix your answer. Remove the wrong information and put in the right information.

Answer (score 6):

Read the [Socket class Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) carefully.

[isConnected](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#isConnected%28%29) is true if the socket was able to connect. The method name is a misnomer, it would more accurate if it was *hasConnected*.

Once the socket successfully connects it becomes true and stays true. Same thing for [isBound](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#isBound%28%29). You have to try a socket operation and check for failure.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure about this, but I'm pretty certain that the underlying BSD Sockets API doesn't actually have a mechanism to determine whether or not a TCP stream is still open; having a `read()` or `write()` fail is a pretty reliable way to tell that the stream has been torn down.